# Symfony: Redirect output of a Process

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-process

I am upgrading an old Symfony application (v2.8) to Symfony 5.3. I am using the process component where the arguments have to be passed in another way than before.

My previous code was like

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$cmd = sprintf('mysqldump mydatabase > %s', $outputTarget);
$process = new Process($cmd);
$process->run();
```

Now, Symfony's Process constructor expects the binary and the arguments to be passed as array ([see here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage)).

How can I achieve the output redirection with the new style?

```php
$process = new Process(['mysqldump', 'mydatabase', '>', $outputTarget]);
$process->run();
```

Won't work, because the `>` would be escaped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a workaround. `Process::fromShellCommandline` can be used to redirect the output. This is my solution:

```php
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('mysqldump mydatabase > "$OUTPUT_TARGET"');
$process->start(null, [
    'OUTPUT_TARGET' => $outputTarget,
]);
```

This way the arguments get passed as environment variables to the process and the OS (or the shell?) takes care about replacing the placeholders of the command by the env.